# Powershell progressbar not showing if convert in exe

Tags: powershell

If I execute the script in the console the progress bar is shown perfectly, but if I convert the script to exe with `ps2exe` the progress bar is not shown.

How can I solve this issue? Thank you

```
$totalTimes = 10
$i = 0

for ($i=0;$i -lt $totalTimes; $i++) {
   $percentComplete = ($i / $totalTimes) * 100
   Write-Progress -Activity 'Doing thing' -Status "Did thing $i  times" -PercentComplete $percentComplete
   sleep 1
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried with [PS2EXE-GUI](https://github.com/MScholtes/TechNet-Gallery/tree/master/PS2EXE-GUI)?

It "converts" PowerShell scripts to EXE Files, optionally as GUI applications:

```
.\ps2exe.ps1 -noconsole -inputFile 'test.ps1' -outputFile 'test.exe'
```

If `test.ps1` contains your sample code, running  `.\test.exe` will show a GUI progress bar such as the following:

[image]

Comment: the key here is the '-noConsole'  without that the progressbar doesnt show

Comment: oh.. and eth latest version of ps2exe seems to be at https://github.com/MScholtes/PS2EXE

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a custom progress bar instead:

```
Remove-Variable * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

function progress_bar($pctg_complete, $label, $leftend = "[", $rightend = "]", $counter = "#", $filler = ".", $completed = $false, $color = "white", $bar_length = 10)
{
    $pctg_complete = [math]::ceiling($pctg_complete)  # making it a INT

    # here $bar_length can be adjusted to increase the size of the PROGRESS BAR

    if ($label -eq $null) # if no LABEL given then use this 
    {
        $label = "My Process"
    }
    if ($completed -eq $true)  # to CLOSE the progress bar
    {
        write-host "`r`b" -NoNewline
        $pctg_complete = 100
        $progress_bar = "$label $leftend" + ($counter*$bar_length*($pctg_complete/10)) + ($filler*$bar_length*((100 - $pctg_complete)/10)) + "$rightend $pctg_complete %"
        write-host $progress_bar -NoNewline -ForegroundColor $color

    }
    else
    {
        $progress_bar = "$label $leftend" + ($counter*$bar_length*($pctg_complete/10)) + ($filler*$bar_length*((100 - $pctg_complete)/10)) + "$rightend $pctg_complete %"
        write-host $progress_bar -NoNewline -ForegroundColor $color
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        if ($pctg_complete -ne 100)
        {
            write-host "`r`b" -NoNewline

        }

    }

}

## SIMPLE USAGE
# simple progress bar with "#" counters and Label=Test
progress_bar -pctg_complete 10 -label "Test"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
progress_bar -pctg_complete 50 -label "Test"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
# should have one of this (or both) at end of your process, to close the progress bar
progress_bar -pctg_complete 100 -label "Test"
progress_bar -completed $true -label "Test"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

#OUTPUT:
#Test [##################################################..................................................] 50 %

## ADVANCED USAGE
# here giving percentage complete in decimals
# giving unicode characters ░ as filler and █ as counter
# also using "|" as the left and right end character
# also modifying the color to Green
progress_bar -pctg_complete 8.9 -label "Test" -counter "$( [char]0x2588 )" -filler "$( [char]0x2591 )" -leftend "|" -rightend "|" -color Green
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
progress_bar -pctg_complete 45.6 -label "Test" -counter "$( [char]0x2588 )" -filler "$( [char]0x2591 )" -leftend "|" -rightend "|" -color Green
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
progress_bar -pctg_complete 98.523 -label "Test" -counter "$( [char]0x2588 )" -filler "$( [char]0x2591 )" -leftend "|" -rightend "|" -color Green
progress_bar -completed $true -label "Test" -counter "$( [char]0x2588 )" -filler "$( [char]0x2591 )" -leftend "|" -rightend "|" -color Green
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

#OUTPUT:
#Test |███████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░| 46 %
```