# How to run a batch script without the window flashing?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

using suggestions from a previous a question ([Kill process after timeout when homonym processes are open - batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67385557/kill-process-after-timeout-when-homonym-processes-are-open-batch)) I was able to kill homonym processes after a timeout:

```
popd
pushd mypath
for /f %%i in ('powershell "(Start-Process myapp.exe -passthru).ID"') do (
timeout /t 180
taskkill /PID %%i
)
```

However, I would like to start the process without a window displaying (and flashing).
I found many questions, such as: [How to run a PowerShell script without displaying a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802127/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-without-displaying-a-window) but I was not able to combine them to my script. How can I do that?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you try ‘-WindowStyle’ hidden? Start-Process has the same same parameter.

Comment: @mklement0 what do you think about something like PS2Exe to "compile" the script. I haven't tried this but, from my reading it seems like it leverages an alternate host.  It also has a `-NoConsole` parameter that may satisfy the requirement.  Admittedly, wrapping a script in an EXE to wrap in a BAT seems a little Russian doll, but should at least address the core question of hiding the window.  Also, I know there may be VS false positive issues... I almost put this in an answer with references, but thought it might be better as a comment for now.

Comment: @Steven, yes, PS2Exe-GUI is an option, though AV software may (mistakenly) complain about it; please see my answer, which tries to give an overview of the various options.

Answer (score 3):

**tl; dr**

To hide *only* the console window that results from use of [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) with a console application (`myapp.exe` in your case), use `-WindowStyle Hidden`, as shown [in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67759668/45375), but you can also streamline and shorten your code by performing *all* operations in a single `powershell.exe` call:

```
@echo off

powershell.exe -c "if (-not ($ps = Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden myapp.exe -PassThru).WaitForExit(60000)) { Stop-Process $ps }"
```

---

**Use cases:**

- What you wanted is to **hide the console window that by default results from PowerShell's [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)** launching a *console application* (which isn't normally done, because *direct*, *synchronous* execution is by far the most common use case - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375)):

  - **`-WindowStyle Hidden`** hides this new window; note that you won't be able to see or capture any output, unless you request redirection to *files* via the
    `-RedirectStandardOutput` and `-RedirectStandardError` parameters; also, in order to check the *exit code* you need to use `-PassThru` so as to obtain an object that represents the newly launched process.
  - If you want to see the program's output in the *current* console window - albeit without being able to *capture* it - use **`-NoNewWindow`**, which, however, only makes sense if you also use `-Wait`, otherwise the asynchronously running program's output will interfere with your display (and if you're waiting anyway, direct, synchronous invocation is the better option).
  - As an aside: on Unix-like platforms, `-WindowStyle` isn't supported, and `-NoNewWindow` is *implied*, which mostly makes `Start-Process` only useful for launching *GUI* programs on Unix (including launching URLs in order to open them in the default web browser; e.g. `Start-Process http://example.org`)
- However, your question's title might lead people to think your intent is to **run *the batch file itself* - or any console application, including [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) or [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) (PowerShell 7)  - invisibly**:

  - **Windows currently offers *no* direct mechanism for that**; launching a console application invariably creates a *visible* console for it. A solution therefore requires a *GUI-subsystem* helper file or mechanism that (a) itself doesn't create a console window and (b) allows *hiding* the automatically console window when launching the target console application (however, a [**potential future enhancement**](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/main/doc/specs/%237335%20-%20Console%20Allocation%20Policy.md) is being discussed, *conditional* allocation of a console, which would allow applications to decide whether or not to allocate a console based on runtime conditions, but note that only applications designed to use this feature would then offer situational no-console launching).
  - For now, there are several **solutions**:

    - **Call via `mshta.exe:`**; a simple example that runs `powershell.exe` itself invisibly and ultimately opens Notepad; you can run it from the Windows `Run` dialog (<kbd>Win-R</kbd>) to verify that no console window is created for PowerShell:

      ```
       mshta.exe vbscript:(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("powershell -c notepad.exe",0))(Window.Close)
      ```

      - ***Caveat*: AV software may prevent this invocation mechanism.**
    - Use an **auxiliary WSH script** (`*.vbs` or `*.js`) launched via the GUI-subsystem `wscript.exe` host - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41229169/45375).
    - Use the **third-party [RunHiddenConsole](https://github.com/SeidChr/RunHiddenConsole) project**, which offers a **generic GUI-subsystem *helper executable*** that you name for your target executable with `w` appended.
    - Use **Python**:

      - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7006424/45375).
    - In the context of **PowerShell**, specifically:

      - Use a GUI-subsystem **wrapper executable** for PowerShell scripts that the third-party **[PS2EXE-GUI](https://github.com/MScholtes/TechNet-Gallery/tree/master/PS2EXE-GUI) script** can create for you; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53176060/45375) for an example.

        - **Note**: The wrapper-generating script must be run in *Windows PowerShell* and the resulting `*.exe` too executes via the Windows PowerShell SDK.
      - The **[*PowerShell (Core) 7* CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh), `pwsh.exe`, may itself offer a solution *in the future***, as discussed in [GitHub issue #3028](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3028#issuecomment-675714111), based on the previously linked planned system-level enhancement, *conditional* console allocation).

Answer (score 2):

Following Steven's comment I added `-WindowStyle Hidden` also inside the loop. Here the solution:

```
pushd mypath
for /f %%i in ('powershell -WindowStyle Hidden -"(Start-Process myapp.exe -passthru -WindowStyle Hidden).ID"') do (
timeout /t 180
taskkill /PID %%i
)
```