# How to run python code from powershell with no command prompt showing?

Tags: python, windows, powershell

I would like to be able to run a python script from a .ps1 file without the terminal window showing up to run the script. I would think that there is some extra command I can put at the end to make it run windowless, but I am not sure what it is.

The only code I have in the ps1 file is to execute the python script by linking the path.

I do not want to run the code some way else, it has to be from a ps1 script since I will be adding to it eventually to have more features. I also would rather not have to change the file to a .pyw if possible.

```
E:/script.py
```

*Note - I ran the file from a different drive this time, but I want it to be from E:/ like I have in my code.

What I don't want to show up:
[image: What I don't want to show up]

Comment: @mklement0 im using run (WIN + R) and this command: powershell -w h iex (E:\a.ps1)

Answer (score 3):

In a comment you state:

> im using run (WIN + R) and this command: `powershell -w h iex (E:\a.ps1)`

- `-w h` is short for `-WindowStyle Hidden`
- `iex` is short for `Invoke-Expression`, which is *not* needed here - and should generally be avoided: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).

Note: While this does make the console window that the PowerShell session *itself* runs in invisible, the window becomes invisible only *after briefly showing first*.

- To avoid this brief flashing of the console window, `powershell.exe` must be launched *indirectly*, namely via a GUI-subsystem application that launches it with a hidden window; the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67761779/45375) discusses options.
- Also note that supporting this *directly* in the future is planned, but will likely only be implemented for the CLI of *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, `pwsh.exe` - see [GitHub issue #3028](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3028#issuecomment-675714111).

---

With that out of the way:

- *Console* applications (including `.ps1` scripts) invoked directly from a hidden PowerShell session run hidden too, because they run directly in the hidden console window.
- By contrast, any *GUI* applications or applications of either type invoked via [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) run *visibly*.

  - While you can generally use `Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden` to run GUI applications invisibly as well, this, unfortunately, does *not* seem to work with `.pyw` files, i.e. `pythonw.exe`-launched scripts, which still run visibly.<sup>[1]</sup>

By default, `.py` files invoked directly execute via `py.exe`, which *is* a console application.

Strangely, your screen shot suggests that it is *not* in your case.

`py.exe` is normally just a launcher for the true console Python executable (allowing you to switch between v2 and v3 versions of Python with `py -2 ...` and `py -3 ...`), `python.exe`, so as a workaround you can try the following (use a *full* path to `python.exe`, if needed):

- Modify your `E:\a.ps1` script to explicitly invoke your `.py` script with `python.exe`:

```
python.exe E:\script.py
```

- Then launch your invisible PowerShell session as before, except with improved syntax:

```
# Short for:
#   powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -File E:\a.ps1
powershell -w h -f E:\a.ps1
```

If that doesn't help, consider reinstalling Python.

---

<sup>[1] I'm *guessing* this is because the windows potentially created by the `.pyw` scripts themselves are unrelated to the (invisible) main window of the `pythonw.exe` GUI-subsystem executable.</sup>

Comment: How can I launch a python script without having to specify `python.exe`? In other words, being able to execute a script called `some.py`, by only typing it's name?

Comment: @not2qubit, for that (a) `$env:PATHEXT` must have a `.py` entry and (b) a file association for `.py` must exist that defines the interpreter to use for such files. As far as I know, Python installers set that up automatically, but depending on your installation method it may not be set up.

Comment: Yes, I have already done that, and was looking at some other comments by *Eryk Sun*, and it seem that whatever was said before doesn't work anymore. (Using py3.12.1 on Win-11 Pro) I also made sure to install the `py` launcher & checking the paths, assoc, ftype etc.

Comment: @not2qubit: That's odd. I suggest asking a new question specifically about that.

Answer (score -1):

```
Start-Process python -ArgumentList "python-script-file-path" -NoNewWindow
```

Lots of excellent info [here.](https://superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background/591084#591084)

Comment: `Start-Process -NoNewWindow` is asking for trouble, because it _asynchronously_ launches a console application in the current console, with its output arriving unpredictably in the current console. To run a Python script _synchronously_ in the current console, just invoke it directly (or by passing its path as an argument to `python.exe` or `py.exe` with `-2` or `-3`).

Comment: While you could add `-Wait` to ensure _synchronous_ execution, there is no reason to use `Start-Process` to begin with in this case: Just invoke `python "python-script-file-path"` directly, which will also run in the current window, invariably _synchronously_, and, perhaps most importantly, with the Python script's output streams connected to PowerShell's streams. [GitHub docs issue #6239](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239) provides guidance on when use of  `Start-Process` is and isn't appropriate.