# Run PowerShell Script from Task Scheduler without Window

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm running an Encoded powershell command from Task Scheduler on user login. The command does some evaluations and will present a message box to the user. The issue I'm having is the PowerShell window still flashes no matter what switches I use. **Note:** the script itself works fine.

This is what I have in task scheduler:

```
powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -executionpolicy bypass -noninteractive -encodedcommand "COMMAND"
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

- `powershell.exe` is a Windows *console*-subsystem application (as is `pwsh.exe`, the PowerShell (Core) CLI).
- Therefore, Windows currently *invariably* creates an - initially visible - *console window* for it when it launches, and only *afterwards* is PowerShell able to honor `-WindowStyle Hidden` and hide the window<sup>[1]</sup> - this causes the flashing you see.

  - Note: It is possible to run scheduled tasks *fundamentally* invisibly, by making them run in the same invisible session that Windows services run, such as running as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` or with the `Run whether user is logged on or not` option, but then you won't be able to interact with the user's desktop, which is what your intent is.
- This is a long-standing problem, discussed in [GitHub issue #3028](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3028).

  - For now, the only **workaround** is to use a *GUI*-subsystem *wrapper* application for launching `powershell.exe` hidden - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67761779/45375) for concrete options.
  - However, a **future Windows enhancement**, the **[Console Allocation Policy](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/main/doc/specs/%237335%20-%20Console%20Allocation%20Policy.md) will offer a solution**: *conditional* allocation of a console, which would allow applications to decide whether or not to allocate a console for themselves based on runtime conditions.
    It is unclear to me when this feature will be available (or even if it is *guaranteed* to be implemented, but I expect it will be).

    - Since using this feature will require opt-in via an application [manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests),  the PowerShell CLI will have to be updated to support that.
    - Given that *Windows PowerShell* is no longer actively maintained, unlike [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), only the latter's CLI, [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), is  likely to be updated.

---

<sup>[1] If *Windows Terminal* is the default terminal application, the resulting window is currently only *minimized*, which is problematic - see [WT GitHub issue #12464](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/12464).</sup>